# Android does each Layout element require an XLMNS definition?

Tags: android, android-layout

I guess this is more of a best practice question.  But does each Layout element (LinearLayout, ReleativeLayout, etc.) need a `xmlns:android` tag?  I know the root tag requires it, but should child Layout elements have it as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, there's no need to add `xmlns` to child elements, unless they require attributes unknown to the sdk (for example, the AdMob SDK)